# Mask real domain name for images?

Tags: image, .htaccess, https, dns

Is it possible to change domain name for images like for example, here is path to my images:

https://example.com/public/-path-to-image

is it possible to change it to for example:

https://example2.com/public/-path-to-image

but still serve images from example.com? I want to hide real path so that users see example2.com instead of example.com and block direct access to my images. Can this be done when using HTTPS on server?

Answer (score 0):

My option is not the perfect one and don't use it unless don't get a better alternative.

Keep the images in `Base64` format instead of storing files. So you can just server the `base64` string instead of the image path

**NOTE:** Base64 will increase the size of image